# ExcelDataReader Datatype "date" gets transformed

Tags: c#, excel, date, exceldatareader

the following code reads the data out of an excel file:

```
        string path = "testtable.xls";

        FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

        foreach (DataTable Table in result.Tables)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < Table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = new DataView(Table);
                }
            }

        }
```

This works for every column just fine, except the column with "dates" in.

In the excel table I specified dates in dd.mm.yyyy but in my gridview I get something like: **42781** instead of **15.02.2017**.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: how do you prevent the date getting converted to datetime? for some reason my dates are being rendered as datetimes with a `12:00:00 AM` suffix! any way to prevent this>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. After changing these two lines it works.

```
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream, true);
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet(true);
```

Comment: this no longer works with the newest versoin of ExcelDataReader

Comment: @AlexGordon - how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

When you are reading excel, you are reading an internal representation of a date.
42781 is the internal representation (days sine 1/1/1900). So you need to convert to a date using DateTime.FromOADate.

In your case, I am afraid you cant bind your table as is. (By the way why are you iterating over columns/rows and setting the binding everytime? You just need to bind the table once.). Anyways you might need to change the table somhow or create a new table with transformed value. Or may be there is some kind of value converter you could use

Comment: You are right, I have cleaned this up. There indeed is some kind of value converter. Posted the code as an answer.

Comment: are you saying you need to cast it prior to reading it into a dataset?

Answer (score 2):

```
  DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet(true);
```

The above line of code is giving the time also after conversion (05/23/2017 12:00 AM)

Comment: how do you disable it fmro giving the time?

Answer (score 1):

You could also calculate the offset like described [here](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/177).

```
 public static DateTime FromExcelDate(double value)
 {
     return new DateTime(1899, 12, 30).AddDays(value);
 }
```

Comment: I already using `CreateBinaryReader(stream, true)` and `excelReader.AsDataSet`, but for some reasons, some excel files still don't have date converted. this solution worked for me (checked if cell value is double, then convert to date)